# SQLite query GROUP BY range

Tags: sqlite, group-by, android-sqlite

Here are my table's columns :

```
Time | Close | High | Low | Open | pairVolume | Trades | Volume
```

I would love to have my data group by range of time.

Now the tricky part is that this range is custom (it's a user input which could very well be grouping by 10 minutes, 2 hours, or even 5 days)

My time field is stored in millisecond since epoch.

**Solution I found for now which I'm uncertain about :**

```
SELECT time + (21600000 - (time%21600000)) as gap, count(time) 
FROM price_chart 
WHERE time >= 1517418000000 and time <= 1518195600000 
GROUP BY gap
```

- 21600000 is 6 hours in milliseconds
- time is time since epoch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it works.

Putting some numbers into excel with your formula below, it works for me. Your gap value will be returned as the top end of each time range grouping.

```
SELECT time + (21600000 - (time%21600000)) as gap ...
```

Using the below:

```
SELECT time - (time%21600000) as gap_bottom ...
```

Would return you the bottom end of each time range grouping. You could add this as an additional calculated column and have both returned.

EDIT / PS:

You can also use the SQLite date formatting functions after dividing 1,000 milliseconds out of your epoch time and converting it to the SQLite `unixepoch`:

```
strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', datetime(1517418000000 / 1000, 'unixepoch') )

... for ...

SELECT  strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', datetime( (time + (21600000 - (time%21600000))) / 1000, 'unixepoch') ) as gap ...
```